# How to add new string to Registry Entry of type REG_MULTI_SZ?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I have 1 registry entry of type REG_MULTI_SZ. This entry already contains some string in it.

Now i want to add 1 more string to it by using .net class`RegistryKey` . this class has method `key.SetValue(string,string)`. But when i use this method it removes all strings which are already there and then inserts new string, in short it overwrites. 
I don't want to touch strings which are already there, just want to add new string at the end.
Anybody know how can we do this in C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a multi string value I would do this.

```
key.SetValue("MultipleStringValue", new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

If it's a single value then as Wolfgang mentioned you should read existing and append.

Comment: if i mention single string then it overwrites old values and also reg entry converts to  type REG_SZ

Comment: key.SetValue("MultipleStringValue", new string[] {"One"}); you should pass an array with single string.

Comment: i checked this,but still it replaces old values

Comment: @sagar, SetValue will replace the existing one and it is expected. If you like to append to multivalues you should maintain a in memory array with existing values and overwrite the same.

Answer (score 6):

As per Vinayak's answer above, if you want to append a value, you would need to read in the existing value and work with that.

So:

```
var registryValue = key.GetValue("KeyName");
```

to get the existing value, which should return a string array for a REG_MULTI_SZ. Then it's just a matter of appending the new value (or swapping out an existing value, if that takes your fancy). You can do this any way you prefer - create a List from the array and add a new value to it, create a new string array with a loop, make use of IEnumerable.Concat...

```
var stringList = new List<string>(registryValue as string[]);
stringList.Add("NewValue");
key.SetValue("KeyName", stringList.ToArray());
```

Obviously you'd want to put some defensive coding around this little sample - make sure you're actually getting back a string array, etc...

Comment: thanks ,i knew this already. i was looking for other possible way

Comment: I don't think there is another possible way, at least not using the Registry class. You could always roll your own registry access library, or create an extension method to effectively do this in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way. You have to read the existing string first, then append your string to that and write the new concatenated string back.

Comment: Thank you, but i m looking other possible way.